# School assignment file manipulations with - operator

Tags: python, text, document

Hello all I have a text document that has two sets of numbers 4-1  and 9-3  code need to read them  and write in a same text document and need to watch out for  newline then the code need to  calculate them and print without entry tnx all for  help

I have tried

```
f = open("Odin.txt","r")
print(f.read())
f.close()


f = open("Odin.txt","w")

for f in line:
    res = eval(line.strip())
    output.write(line.strip()+"="+str(res)+"\n")
f.close()

f = open("Odin.txt","r")
print(f.readline(),end="")
print(f.readline(),end="")
f.close()
```

Comment: You should first decide which language you are using, then explain what *specific*  issue(s) you are having with your coding attempts.

Comment: Some before and after would be handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your option 1 is close, but your `for f in line` is backwards; you wanted `for line in f` (i.e. iterate over each `line` in the `f`ile).  It's also easier if you read the whole file in *before* you start writing out the modified version.

```
# Read a copy of the file into memory as a list.
with open("Odin.txt") as f:
    lines = list(map(str.strip, f.readlines()))

# Write out the new content.
with open("Odin.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        f.write(f"{line}={eval(line)}\n")
```

```
>cat Odin.txt
4-1
9-3

>python odin.py
>cat Odin.txt
4-1=3
9-3=6
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something like this:

```
import re

output = ""

with open("New Text Document.txt", "r") as file:
    # This gets the expression before the "=" and removes all the leading and trailing whitespaces
    text = [(re.sub("=(.*)", "", line)).strip() for line in file.readlines()]

    for line in text:
        try:
            output += f"{line} = {eval(line)}\n"
        except SyntaxError:
            pass

with open("New Text Document.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(output)
```

So basically read the document first and put everything I want to write in the file in a variable. Then I simply open it again in writing mode and write my output.

Comment: no problem at all :)